scipy.integrate.simpson gives different result when x (sampled points) is explicitly given
I was writing a simple integration function using Simpson's rule and was comparing my result to both an analytic result as well as the result from scipy's simpson function (scipy.integrate.simpson). I was evaluating x^2 from 0 to 100 with a step-size of 1 (101 points total, 100 intervals).
I noticed that my result was matching the analytic solution, but not the result from scipy.integrate.simpson, which rounded up the repeating 3 to a 4. So instead of 333333.3333333333, it was giving 333333.3333333334.
Initially, I was giving the array of x values explicitly to the scipy simpson function, but then I tried only giving the y values since the spacing, dx, was 1. This resulted in the output of the scipy simpson function matching the analytic result.
I then tried integrating 3*(x^2) instead of x^2, so that the result wouldn't have an infinite repeating decimal, and this resulted in all four results matching.
Does anyone have any ideas why giving the x-values changed the output of scipy's simpson function  for the case where there's an infinitely repeating decimal? I know the scipy simpson function can handle non-even number of intervals and unevenly spaced points, so perhaps it has to do with that.
from scipy.integrate import simpson
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,100,101)

y = x**2
y_int = (x**3)/3

y_analytic = np.max(y_int) - np.min(y_int)

sci_int = simpson(y,x) #sampled points explicitly given
sci_int_2 = simpson(y) #assumes dx=1

def custom_simpson(x,y):
    a = x[0]
    b = x[-1]

    n = len(x) - 1 #number of intervals

    h = (b-a) / n

    even_y = y[::2]
    odd_y = y[1::2]

    even_y = even_y[1:-1] 
    
    odd_y = np.sum(odd_y)
    even_y = np.sum(even_y)
    
    result = (h/3) * (y[0] + y[-1] + (4*odd_y) + (2*even_y))

    return result


print('hand_made \t', custom_simpson(x,y))
print('analytic \t', y_analytic)
print('scipy_dx=1 \t', sci_int_2)
print('scipy_x_given \t', sci_int)

Output from script when y = x**2:
hand_made        333333.3333333333
analytic         333333.3333333333
scipy_dx=1       333333.3333333333
scipy_x_given    333333.3333333334
Output from script when y = 3 * (x**2):
hand_made        1000000.0
analytic         1000000.0
scipy_dx=1       1000000.0
scipy_x_given    1000000.0

For computers, those two numbers are, for all intents and purposes, the same thing.

Why not find out by yourself. See the source.
